# Example for AWS SDK for PHP to generate CloudWatch event (putEvents)

Tags: php, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm looking to generate an event on CloudWatch by invoking the putEVents on the AWS PHP SDK 3.

I've checked the docu online, especially at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/cw-examples-sending-events.html

But I keep getting an error saying "Detail is malformed". Any help on this? Ideally an example that works would help a lot.

I'm using the following:

```
$client = new CloudWatchEventsClient([
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
   'version' => 'latest'
]);

try {
$result = $client->putEvents([
    'Entries' => [ // REQUIRED
        [
            'Detail' => '4',
            'DetailType' => 'sec',
            'Resources' => ['ec2'],
            'Source' => 'LocalApp'
        ],
    ],
]);
var_dump($result);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by the `Detail` parameter in `putEvents()`. This parameter is a json string.

```
$detail->key = "key";
$detail->value = "4";

$result = $client->putEvents([
    'Entries' => [ // REQUIRED
        [
            'Detail' => json_encode($detail),
            'DetailType' => 'sec',
            'Resources' => ['ec2'],
            'Source' => 'LocalApp'
        ],
    ],
]);
```